# What is the best practice to solve the issue "My bean is null after I new a object"

Tags: java, spring

I have a bean used in MyApp, but when I have MyApp app = new MyApp(), then carIF is null. What is the best practice to solve this issue? I have tried to make MyApp as a bean as well by adding @Component, so I don't need to do 'new MyApp()', but it turns out I need to keep making a java class as bean in my java classes calling workflow, which I don't think it is a right approach. How to solve the issue like this?

```
public class MyApp() {
@Autowired
private CarIF carIF;
```

Comment: May I know why this question should be closed or -1?

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate the class on your own (`MyApp()`) you are not taking advantage of Spring-managed Beans and Spring Dependency Injection features. When you do it like that you can't expect Spring to inject a `CarIF` instance in your newly created `MyApp` instance.

As you mentioned, you should make `MyApp` a Spring-managed Bean by, for example, annotate it with `@Component` as follows:

```java
@Component
public class MyApp() {
   @Autowired
   private CarIF carIF;
}
```

This will generally work, but it really depends on your project setup and if you are following a usual Spring project structure.

Comment: Thanks. I can make MyApp as bean like you mentioned, but  then I also need to make the class which call MyApp as bean, this will be a sequence change, for my project, this sounds not scalable.

Comment: Well but you either use Spring or you don't. If you don't want to add the annotations needed or the configurations that Spring requires then just drop Spring.